# How to wait until DispatcherTimer is stopped?

Tags: c#, .net, dispatchertimer

I have a DispatcherTimer with a Tick event that is stopped after interval.
I stop the DispatcherTimer after amount of time in the tick event like this(using StopWatch):

```
private void DispatcherTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var timeElapsed = _stopwatchTotalProgress.Elapsed;
        if (timeElapsed < selectedBeverage.PreperationTime)
            //do something
        else
        {
            //do somthing
            _dispatcherTimerUpdateProgress.Stop();
            _stopwatchTotalProgress.Reset();
        }
    }
```

I want to write a method (`MyMethod`) (from another class that has a logger mechanism) that print a starting message, starting the dispatcher timer, and when the Dispatcher timer is stopped the method needs to print an ending message, like this:

```
public void MyMethod()
    {
        _logger.notifyMessage("The DispatcherTimer is started");
        _dispatcherTimerUpdateProgress.Start();
        _stopwatchTotalProgress.Start();
        //need to be a kind of waiting until the dispatcher timer is stopped.
        _logger.notifyMessage("The DispatcherTimer is stopped");           
    }
```

My problem with this method is that it prints the ending message before the `_dispatcherTimer` is stopped.
and I tried to use SpinWait or Thread.Sleep, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: why not just put Console.WriteLine("The DispatcherTimer is stopped"); right after you stop the DispatcherTimer in your first method above?

Comment: Because I am calling MyMethod from another class that uses a logger.

Comment: You can start a Task, delay it and await it.

Comment: @Carra thats what I'm looking for but I didn't do it correctly, can you write an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait x seconds, you can delay a Task. Example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var delay = Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_ =>
                           { sw.Stop();
                             return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; } );
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed milliseconds: {0}", delay.Result);
```